# Better way/alternative to animate Height

Tags: css, reactjs

so I have a list of tiles and each of those tiles is able to expand a box underneath itself. When you expand this box, all the other tiles beneath should be pushed down and when you close the expandable, move back up. I am achieving this effect by animating the height of the expandable. With the last 10 or sth tiles it works really smooth, but when toggling the very top ones, the animation is not smooth at all, how can I fix this? I am using React and their CSSTransitionGroup.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen your code but maybe you should consider toggling className with React and make transition of height with CSS, this would be an elegant way to do that.

Comment: thats what I am currently doing, but because of the amount of items on the page, the animation of the first ones is quite laggy